# Bruteforce Time Complexity of Even Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

I am working on a problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/even-tree.

I have though of a solution which is bruteforce in nature. I wanted to verify if this is the correct bruteforce time complexity of this problem. If yes, then I can think of how can I do better.

**Algorithm**

1. Get all subsets of the edges of the given graph(I am getting all combinations of edges so that I can remove them later from the graph). ->O(2PowerE)
2. Start from max subset size.For each subset, remove all these edges from the graph. Run a DFS to figure out whether the remaining disconnected components have even number of nodes. -> O(V+E)
3. Break out of the iterations when certain removal of edges yields the forest with each disconnected component having even number of nodes.

Is the Complexity of the above solution O(2PowerE*(V + E)).
Let me know if this solution works out and qualifies as brute force.

Comment: The maximum number of nodes can be 100. 2^100 is just too big to handle. Maybe dynamic programming will work. Try to find the maximum number of cuttable edges for every subtree.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe is right. Dynamic programming done correctly will provide a polynomial time solution. It will be much more fun working this out than fiddling with the powerset of 99 edges, which is doomed to fail.

Comment: There is no need for a dynamic programming here. There's a simple constructive solution which works in linear time.

Comment: Let's expect an answer from someone who has passed all testcases of the problem. If a greedy algorithm works in O(n), the maximum number of nodes should be raised to 10^4 or more.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe I got AC with this solution (after the contest, I did not take part in this competition). I have also read the editorial after solving it and the model solution is very similar to mine.